# Creating random variable with non-negative sample autocorrelation function in R

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, markov-process

I am interested in generating real numbers with a non-negative *sample* autocorrelation function (acf). It doesn't necessarily matter whether they are simulated or created by other means. In particular, this means that I don't have to be able to specify the acf, but it would be nice if the computational cost is low. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this primarily a question about statistics ("what is a way to approach this kind of problem?") oe a question about R ("what function do I call, with which argument settings?")

Comment: Why has this question been marked off-topic? I can't see why it's not relevant according to the rules

Comment: See out help on what's [on-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) under "programming" and consider how the question in the first comment relates to that.

Comment: Ok, I eliminated the programming words, thats fine with me. Can we reopen the thread now?

Comment: 1. By create  do you mean "simulate" or something more general? 2. Do you want to specify the ACF or is any set of non-negative autocorrelations okay? (3. If you want to specify the ACF is it the sample or the population ACF you want to be able to state?) 4. Does the error distribution matter?

Comment: 1. I added this. 2. I added this. 3. This was already specified. 4. What do you mean by error distribution?

Comment: (on 4.) Sorry to be unclear -- I mean to refer to the conditional distribution of $Y_t$ given the preceding observations. I am guessing from the present version of the question that you don't really mind. I'll reopen but it would be good if you could address it. Is it the case that you need autocorrelations at some set of lags to be non-negative (if so, how many? or is that something you want to choose? Do you want it to be every lag?) or do you just need the first autocorrelation to be non-negative?

Comment: Note that the acf of the values $1,2,3,...,n$ will be positive out to about lag $l=\lfloor n/e \rfloor$. (I say about because definitions of sample acfs differ slightly across books/packages so it's hard to guarantee the precise point it will cross 0), however I'm not sure this answers your question.

Comment: A more "realistic" example is to look at the cumulative sum of a normal with small positive mean (relative to the standard deviation, such as 0.01 and 1 say) -- if $n$ is reasonably large, the first few lags will have positive ACF. e.g. if n=100, out of 1000 tries the first six lags were always positive (typically about 25), and for n=100 the first 58 lags were always positive in 1000 attempts (average was about 250 positive lags).